# div background color not covering full height and width of background image div

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with filling my background color. Default `div` contains an image, when I click next button it activates another `div` with a `background-color` and some text, but still I can see some of my image portion on `div`'s corner.

HTML:

```
<div class="survey_box-active">
  <img src="" />
</div>
<div class="survey_box">
  <h2>Headline</h2>
  <p>some text</>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
survey_box,
survey_box-active {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;

    img {
        display: block;
    }
}

survey_box-active {
    display: block;

}

[class*=survey_box] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f3f3f3;
}
```

Comment: Is the parent element positioned or static?

Comment: Hi, can you post all of your code

Comment: @MichałSadowski position:relative

Comment: As @David said you should share full codes. Where is your button? A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the css of the img tag.

```
img {
    display: block;
    max-width:100%;
}
```